# Input check affecting all classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom-traversal

How can I add a class using jquery without it affecting all divs assigned to that class name? There has to be an easy way around this? I'm already using `$(this)` for the input check, so how can I make the action unique to the toggle it's on?

```
$('input:checkbox').change(function(){
   if($(this).prop('checked')==true){ 
      $(this).closest(".row").toggleClass('highlight', this.checked); 
      $('.overlay').fadeIn(300).delay(3000).fadeOut();
      $(".loader").addClass('active').fadeIn(300).delay(3000).fadeOut();
      setTimeout(function(){
         $(".complete").addClass('active').delay(3300).fadeIn(300).delay(1000).fadeOut()
      }, 3100);
   } else {
      $('.loader').hide(); 
      $('.complete').hide(); 
      $('.overlay').hide(); 
      $(".error").addClass('active').fadeIn(300).delay(2000).fadeOut(200)
   }
});
```

[My jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/daysable/dxq87exz/13/).

Comment: `How can I add a class using jquery without it affecting all divs assigned to that class name` I don't know what this means. What do you mean by `without affecting`?

Comment: When I click my input to be "checked", i have certain classes that are activating from this check. and because I have multiple inputs, the classes are activating for all toggles/inputs not just the one I am toggling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like you are using `$(this).closest(".row")`, instead of `$('.loader')`, `$('.complete')` and `$('.error')` you can use:

```
var container = $(this).closest(".toggle-container")
container.find('.loader')
container.find('.complete')
container.find('.error')
```

Demo below:

```js
$('input:checkbox').change(function() {
  var container = $(this).closest(".toggle-container");
  if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
    $(this).closest(".row").toggleClass('highlight', this.checked);
    $('.overlay').fadeIn(300).delay(3000).fadeOut();
    container.find(".loader").addClass('active').fadeIn(300).delay(3000).fadeOut();
    setTimeout(function() {
      container.find(".complete").addClass('active').delay(3300).fadeIn(300).delay(1000).fadeOut()
    }, 3100);
  } else {
    container.find('.loader').hide();
    container.find('.complete').hide();
    $('.overlay').hide();
    container.find(".error").addClass('active').fadeIn(300).delay(2000).fadeOut(200)
  }
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  background: #edf1f4;
}

.overlay {
  background: rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.5);
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  background: #fcfcfc;
}

.highlight {
  z-index: 700;
  background: none;
  position: absolute;
}

.title {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 24px;
}


/* toggle item  */

.toggle-item {
  text-align: right;
}

.toggle {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
}

.toggle input {
  display: none;
}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
  text-align: initial;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked+.slider {
  background-color: #0272B6;
}

input:focus+.slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #0272B6;
}

input:checked+.slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}

.toggle-label {
  font-size: 9px;
  line-height: 11px;
  letter-spacing: 0.56px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: inline-block;
}

.toggle-label:first-child {
  margin: 10px 8px 0 10px;
}


/* rounded sliders */

.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.toggle-container {
  display: inline-block;
}

.toggle-container:first-child {
  margin-right: 30px;
}

.toggle-title {
  font-weight: 400;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}


/* end of toggle item */

.loader {
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  border-top: 2px solid #0272B6;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 0 5px 0 0;
  display: none;
  position: relative;
}

.complete,
.error {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: relative;
  display: none;
}

.inactive {
  display: none;
}

.active {
  display: inline-block;
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="overlay"></div>
<div class="row">
  <!-- toggle 1 -->
  <div class="toggle-container">
    <div class="loader"></div>
    <div class="complete"><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/my-account-prototype/green-check.png" alt="complete"></div>
    <div class="error"><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/my-account-prototype/red-warning.png" alt="error"></div>
    <p class="toggle-title">Email</p>
    <label class="toggle" for="check-1">
        <input type="checkbox"id="check-1" class="checkmark">
        <div class="slider round data-usage">
         <span class="toggle-label">on</span><span class="toggle-label">off</span>
         </div>
     </label>
  </div>
  <!-- toggle 2 -->
  <div class="toggle-container">
    <div class="loader"></div>
    <div class="complete"><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/my-account-prototype/green-check.png" alt="complete"></div>
    <div class="error"><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/my-account-prototype/red-warning.png" alt="error"></div>
    <p class="toggle-title">Text</p>
    <label class="toggle" for="check-2">
        <input type="checkbox"id="check-2" class="checkmark">
        <div class="slider round data-usage">
          <span class="toggle-label">on</span><span class="toggle-label">off</span>  
        </div>
      </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This worked perfectly and is exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dxq87exz/17/)**.

You've to use the current object `$(this)` with `loader` and `complete` too, else you'll affect all the element with classes `loader/complete`.

So just define the parent div then get the element related to it by changing the two line for `".loader"` and `".complete"` like :

```
var parent_div = $(this).closest(".toggle-container");

parent_div.find(".loader").addClass('active')...;

setTimeout(function(){
    parent_div.find(".complete").addClass('active')..
}, 3100);
```

Hope this helps.

```js
$('input:checkbox').change(function(){
  if($(this).prop('checked')==true){ 
    var parent_div = $(this).closest(".toggle-container");
    $(this).closest(".row").toggleClass('highlight', this.checked); 

    $('.overlay').fadeIn(300).delay(3000).fadeOut();
    parent_div.find(".loader").addClass('active').fadeIn(300).delay(3000).fadeOut();

    setTimeout(function(){
      parent_div.find(".complete").addClass('active').delay(3300).fadeIn(300).delay(1000).fadeOut();
    }, 3100);
  } else {
    $('.loader').hide(); 
    $('.complete').hide(); 
    $('.overlay').hide(); 
    $(".error").addClass('active').fadeIn(300).delay(2000).fadeOut(200)
  }
});
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.container {
  width: 100%;
  background: #edf1f4;
}
.overlay {
    background: rgba(128,128,128,0.5);
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0; 
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.row {
  display: flex;
  background: #fcfcfc;

}
.highlight {
  z-index: 700;
  background: none;
  position: absolute;
}

.title {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 24px;
}


/* toggle item  */
.toggle-item {
  text-align: right;
}
.toggle {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
}
.toggle input {
  display:none;
}
.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
  text-align: initial;
}
.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}
input:checked + .slider {
  background-color: #0272B6;
}
input:focus + .slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #0272B6;
}
input:checked + .slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
} 
.toggle-label {
  font-size: 9px;
  line-height: 11px;
  letter-spacing: 0.56px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: inline-block;
}
.toggle-label:first-child {
  margin: 10px 8px 0 10px;
}
/* rounded sliders */
.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.toggle-container {
  display: inline-block;
}
.toggle-container:first-child {
  margin-right: 30px;
}
.toggle-title {
  font-weight: 400;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
} 
/* end of toggle item */
.loader {
    border: 2px solid #ccc; 
    border-top: 2px solid #0272B6; 
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin: 0 5px 0 0;
    display: none;
    position: relative;
}
.complete,
.error {
 width: 20px;
 height: 20px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: relative;
  display: none;
}
.inactive {
  display: none;
}
.active {
  display: inline-block;
}

 @keyframes spin {
    0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
    100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="overlay"></div>
<div class="row">
  <!-- toggle 1 -->
  <div class="toggle-container">
    <div class="loader"></div>
    <div class="complete"><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/my-account-prototype/green-check.png" alt="complete"></div>
    <div class="error"><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/my-account-prototype/red-warning.png" alt="error"></div>
    <p class="toggle-title">Email</p>
    <label class="toggle" for="check-1">
      <input type="checkbox"id="check-1" class="checkmark">
      <div class="slider round data-usage">
        <span class="toggle-label">on</span><span class="toggle-label">off</span>
      </div>
    </label>  
  </div>
  <!-- toggle 2 -->
  <div class="toggle-container">
    <div class="loader"></div>
    <div class="complete"><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/my-account-prototype/green-check.png" alt="complete"></div>
    <div class="error"><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/my-account-prototype/red-warning.png" alt="error"></div>
    <p class="toggle-title">Text</p>
    <label class="toggle" for="check-2">
      <input type="checkbox"id="check-2" class="checkmark">
      <div class="slider round data-usage">
        <span class="toggle-label">on</span><span class="toggle-label">off</span>  
      </div>
    </label>  
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/fm9ko5xy/1/

you can use the `.eq()` and its complementary method `.index()`

This line gets the index number of the currently selected checkbox

```
let inputIndex = $('input:checkbox').index($(this));
```

These lines(and more) are simply appended with the `.eq(inputIndex)` method to tell the script which specific element to affect.

```
$('.overlay').eq(inputIndex).fadeIn(300).delay(3000).fadeOut();
$(".loader").eq(inputIndex).addClass('active').fadeIn(300).delay(3000).fadeOut();
...
```

**Local Code Snippet:**

```js
$('input:checkbox').change(function(){
 let inputIndex = $('input:checkbox').index($(this));
  if($(this).prop('checked')==true){ 
  $(this).closest(".row").toggleClass('highlight', this.checked); 
  
 

  $('.overlay').eq(inputIndex).fadeIn(300).delay(3000).fadeOut();
  $(".loader").eq(inputIndex).addClass('active').fadeIn(300).delay(3000).fadeOut();
  setTimeout(function(){
  $(".complete").eq(inputIndex).addClass('active').delay(3300).fadeIn(300).delay(1000).fadeOut()
  }, 3100);
   } else {
      $('.loader').eq(inputIndex).hide(); 
       $('.complete').eq(inputIndex).hide(); 
       $('.overlay').eq(inputIndex).hide(); 
      $(".error").eq(inputIndex).addClass('active').fadeIn(300).delay(2000).fadeOut(200)
   }
});
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.container {
  width: 100%;
  background: #edf1f4;
}
.overlay {
    background: rgba(128,128,128,0.5);
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0; 
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.row {
  display: flex;
  background: #fcfcfc;

}
.highlight {
  z-index: 700;
  background: none;
  position: absolute;
}

.title {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 24px;
}


/* toggle item  */
.toggle-item {
  text-align: right;
}
.toggle {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
}
.toggle input {
  display:none;
}
.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
  text-align: initial;
}
.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}
input:checked + .slider {
  background-color: #0272B6;
}
input:focus + .slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #0272B6;
}
input:checked + .slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
} 
.toggle-label {
  font-size: 9px;
  line-height: 11px;
  letter-spacing: 0.56px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: inline-block;
}
.toggle-label:first-child {
  margin: 10px 8px 0 10px;
}
/* rounded sliders */
.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.toggle-container {
  display: inline-block;
}
.toggle-container:first-child {
  margin-right: 30px;
}
.toggle-title {
  font-weight: 400;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
} 
/* end of toggle item */
.loader {
    border: 2px solid #ccc; 
    border-top: 2px solid #0272B6; 
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin: 0 5px 0 0;
    display: none;
    position: relative;
}
.complete,
.error {
 width: 20px;
 height: 20px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: relative;
  display: none;
}
.inactive {
  display: none;
}
.active {
  display: inline-block;
}

 @keyframes spin {
    0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
    100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="overlay"></div>
<div class="row">
<!-- toggle 1 -->
  <div class="toggle-container">
      <div class="loader"></div>
      <div class="complete"><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/my-account-prototype/green-check.png" alt="complete"></div>
    <div class="error"><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/my-account-prototype/red-warning.png" alt="error"></div>
      <p class="toggle-title">Email</p>
      <label class="toggle" for="check-1">
        <input type="checkbox"id="check-1" class="checkmark">
        <div class="slider round data-usage">
         <span class="toggle-label">on</span><span class="toggle-label">off</span>
         </div>
     </label>  
    </div>
    <!-- toggle 2 -->
    <div class="toggle-container">
       <div class="loader"></div>
      <div class="complete"><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/my-account-prototype/green-check.png" alt="complete"></div>
    <div class="error"><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/my-account-prototype/red-warning.png" alt="error"></div>
      <p class="toggle-title">Text</p>
      <label class="toggle" for="check-2">
        <input type="checkbox"id="check-2" class="checkmark">
        <div class="slider round data-usage">
          <span class="toggle-label">on</span><span class="toggle-label">off</span>  
        </div>
      </label>  
    </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> How can I add a class using jquery without it affecting all divs assigned to that class name?

I think what you mean is *how do I affect specific related elements to the checkbox*.

Use a container:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('input').on('click', function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    var $container = $this.closest('.mycontainer');
    var $related = $container.find('.related');
    $related.toggleClass('red');
  });
});
```

```css
.red{
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mycontainer">
       <input type="checkbox">
       <span class="related">Hello</span>
    </div>
    <div class="mycontainer">
       <input type="checkbox">
       <span class="related">Hello</span>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change code with this and check if it works for you.

Only issue here is class selector selects all elements from DOM with same classname which changes both of your checkboxes
I avoided to use this as a reference as its  reference would change in setTimeout function.

```
$('input:checkbox').change(function(event){
var $this = $(event.target).closest('.toggle-container');
  if($(event.target).prop('checked')==true){ 
  $this.parents(".row").toggleClass('highlight', this.checked); 
  $this.find('.overlay').fadeIn(300).delay(3000).fadeOut();
  $this.find(".loader").addClass('active').fadeIn(300).delay(3000).fadeOut();
  setTimeout(function(){
  $this.find(".complete").addClass('active').delay(3300).fadeIn(300).delay(1000).fadeOut()
  }, 3100);
   } else {
      $this.find('.loader').hide(); 
       $this.find('.complete').hide(); 
       $this.find('.overlay').hide(); 
      $this.find(".error").addClass('active').fadeIn(300).delay(2000).fadeOut(200)
   }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of modifying the existing class applied on multiple divs, create a new class and add on a single div.